# In Watson conversation, How to turn on fuzzy matching only for synonyms and not for the value?

Tags: watson-conversation

I am modelling a conversation in Watson conversation. The conversation is around the facilities available at airports. I have configured airport names as an entity and have added variations of airport names as synonyms and have kept the IATA code for the airport as the entity value. For example, Schiphol airport in Amsterdam looks like the below

[image]

I have turned on fuzzy matching on this entity so that I can catch typos people will make when they try to say Schiphol or Amsterdam. However, Watson is now capturing the word `am` in the below sentence as this entity

`I am wondering if there is wifi in schiphol airport?`

How do I stop Watson from fuzzy matching on the entity value but only do it on synonyms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to enable Fuzzy matching on synonyms only, at the moment. I see a couple of "easy" workarounds.

**Option 1**: Leverage Watson's confidence level.

If you place `<? entities ?>` within your node's response and test it in the *Try it out panel*, you'll notice that each detected entity has a confidence level associated with it. This is Watson's confidence level in the entity, expressed as a float ranging from 0 to 1.

When testing it with your entity value and synonyms, I got 90% confidence (i.e., 0.9) for `amsterdaam` but only 70% for `am`.

So assuming these numbers hold for you, you could use `entities[0].confidence > 0.7` as the condition in your node to decide when to assign the airport to a context variable and when to ask for clarification from the user in the response.

You might have to do some testing to see if you can find a confidence level value that works reasonably well as a threshold for your `@airport` entity values and their common misspellings.

**Option 2**: Use two entities

1. `@airport-code`: Use the airport code for the value, no synonyms, and no fuzzy matching enabled.
2. `@airport-name`: Use the airport name for the value, various synonyms including city, and fuzzy matching enabled.

Depending on how your chatbot works, this might be an acceptable compromise or complicate too much your logic.

I'll give you an example. If your `$airport` context variable will work whether `AMS` or `Amsterdam Airport Schiphol` is stored, this solution solves the problem for you as is. If not, there is an extra step before you can assign the value to the `$airport` context variable. Namely, you may need to implement a lookup to retrieve the airport code for the given airport name.

Comment: I went ahead with your suggestion on confidence threshold which is working fine for the limited use cases that I am aware of. I will keep an eye during the wider test to see how does it perform.